# How to make invalid declaration form?

Tags: privacy, fraud, india

I am planning to leave my company, but my manager forced me to sign the declaration form, the form contains,

- I will work part-time
- I will update new technology
- I will support continuously
- I will share my knowledge

If i do not sign the above declaration form they will not relieve me, how to handle this situation, i got placed High reputation MNC company. Is this declaration form affect my future? please help me.

Comment: What country are you in? Typically forms/contracts signed under duress are invalid. What your employer is asking you to do looks to basically be employment without pay, so that may be invalid as well. Another thing is that it may need is an expiration date... I'm guessing that the country is India?

Comment: Yes, i am from India

Comment: Not mentioned duration time, he forced me to sign the declaration form. How can i handle this in the future suppose they blackmail in any manner?

Comment: If you already signed it, you need to contact a lawyer ASAP.

Comment: No, tomorrow is my last day, they told me to sign the declaration form then you will get a relieving letter and the remaining documents.

Comment: Noted lawyer, any other alternative ways available to handle this situation?

Comment: Ron touched on this idea, but what does the form, or any other documentation, say about your compensation (consideration) for carrying out those activities?

Comment: They want to blackmail to do their job, that's it. In what is the way this is affecting my career? how to escape from this bad?

Comment: FYI - I have close to another manager, shall i get mail verification from him regard there is no pending work and no signed any other bond. Is this idea will work. He will okay with this idea because he will resign next month. In the future, this idea will work? In the future, i will argue this is fake i got all clearance from official mail.

Comment: Is any other document help me with all the things clear with this company?

Comment: You really need legal advice from someone (a lawyer, really) familiar with your specific situation.  A misunderstanding of the details could severely impact your future obligations.

Comment: Still, i am not signed, but i need to sign for my relieving letter then only they given. How to make invalid, shall i put a wrong sign, do these things make the form invalid?